# Making POST request in VBA. Message Payload getting split across lines after 1023 characters

Tags: excel, vba, rest

I am making a post request via Excel VBA.  While I am building one long string, the POST is failing and I am assuming it is because the string seems to be getting a carriage return at around 1023 characters.  At least that is what is happening in in the Debug.Print().  If I copy the output from the console window, and put it into something like "POSTMAN", and remove the carriage return - it works.  So I know the query is being assembled correctly.

Very long query string being generated with no carriage returns.

```
 strQuery = "{" & Chr(34) & "query" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & "SELECT SMRTPLAN.RequestNumber AS RequestNumber,SMRTPLAN.DESCRIPTIONS AS Descriptions, SMRTGENERALPLAN.SubmissionType,SMRTPUBLISHMETA.SubmissionTypeValue, SMRTPLAN.WRType AS WRType, SMRTDISPATCHINFO.FirstDocSubmissionID, SMRTDISPATCHINFO.FinalDocIDAndVersionNumber, pr.ProductsRegNo,CountryRegNo,SMRTPLAN.WRStatus AS WRStatus FROM [DBO].[PLAN] SMRTPLAN LEFT JOIN [DBO].[GENERALPLANNING] SMRTGENERALPLAN ON SMRTPLAN.REQUESTNUMBER = SMRTGENERALPLAN.REQUESTNUMBER LEFT JOIN [DBO].[OTHERCONSIDERATIONSKPIPRINTINGINFORMATION] SMRTOTHERPRINT ON SMRTPLAN.REQUESTNUMBER = SMRTOTHERPRINT.REQUESTNUMBER LEFT JOIN [DBO].[PLANT2] SMRTPLANT2 ON SMRTPLAN.REQUESTNUMBER = SMRTPLANT2.REQUESTNUMBER LEFT JOIN [DBO].[DISPATCHINFORMATION] SMRTDISPATCHINFO ON SMRTPLAN.REQUESTNUMBER = SMRTDISPATCHINFO.REQUESTNUMBER LEFT JOIN [DBO].[PublishingMetadata] SMRTPUBLISHMETA ON SMRTPLAN.REQUESTNUMBER = SMRTPUBLISHMETA.REQUESTNUMBER "
 strQuery = strQuery & "LEFT OUTER JOIN eCTDBase SMRTBASE ON SMRTPLAN.REQUESTNUMBER = SMRTBASE.REQUESTNUMBER "
 strQuery = strQuery & "LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductRegistration pr ON SMRTPLAN.RequestNumber = pr.RequestNumber "
 strQuery = strQuery & "LEFT OUTER JOIN RegistrationMapping RM ON pr.RegistrationID =rm.RegistrationID "
 strQuery = strQuery & "WHERE  smrtplan.RequestNumber = '" & strWR & "' GROUP BY SMRTPLAN.RequestNumber,Descriptions, "
 strQuery = strQuery & "WRType, SubmissionManager, PrintDispatchCoordinator, WRStatus,RegisterData, ProductsRegNo,CountryRegNo, SubmissionTypeValue,SubmissionType,FirstDocSubmissionID,FinalDocIDAndVersionNumber" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "dmlType" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "SELECT" & Chr(34) & "}"
```

Output in console, split over 2 lines (hard carriage return visible when I copy it out to other programs).

[image]

Copying it into a REST tester, and just removing this carriage return manually in the RAW post body, it works as expected, so the query is correct.  In Excel I just get "bad client ID", which I think is just from what it perceives as a malformed body being sent in the POST request.

Response in something like POSTMAN of this query.

```
[
    {
        "SubmissionType": "Development",
        "SubmissionTypeValue": "Development: Change Clinical",
        "FirstDocSubmissionID": "",
        "FinalDocIDAndVersionNumber": "",
        "WRType": "Publishing Required",
        "ProductsRegNo": "",
        "CountryRegNo": "",
        "RequestNumber": "WR12345",
        "Descriptions": "Testing on 9th Mar - 3rd on 13thMar",
        "WRStatus": "Work Request Created"
    }
]
```

So how can I force Excel to not split this string into two lines.  Putting it into Excel, it seems to be when we are at around 1023 characters the split happens.

People are asking for the POST code.  Here it is:

```
 Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' SIT
    strUrl = "https://mycompany.com/api/t/azure/1/reg"
    client_id = "0000000000000000000000000000"
    client_secret = "11111111111111111111111111"
    
   
    
    blnAsync = True

    With objRequest
        
        .Open "POST", strUrl, blnAsync
        
        .setRequestHeader "Client_Id", client_id
        .setRequestHeader "Client_Id", client_id
        .setRequestHeader "Client_Secret", client_secret
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        
       
        
        .Send strQuery
        
        'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
        While objRequest.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        strResponse = .responseText
       
End With
```

Comment: Pretty sure what you're seeing is the maximum line length limit in the VB editor of 1024 characters for a single line of code.   If the actual POST is failing then maybe include that code in your question: it's not going to be due to some limit on string length in VBA (you are nowhere near that).

Comment: print the string to a cell somewhere and copy/paste that

Comment: @TimWilliams the post is fine with that query in POSTMAN, but I have to manually remove that carriage return from the VBA output.  So I am confident in the VBA posting code.  It works for areas where the payload is not as long, just this one fails.. I added the post code.

Comment: @CDP1802 how will that help, I still have to build it up as a variable, and that's where the problem kicks in.  Or do you mean to generate a formula with the string calculated in it

Comment: I meant you can prove there is no carriage return in it and the console is adding it.

Comment: @CDP1802 if it was only the console adding it, the whole thing would work.  As I said, adding the query from the console works in POSTMAN, as long as I remove the carriage return.  I can only assume the carriage return is now part of the string variable and this is why it is broken on the Send

Comment: Why are you the adding the client_id header to the request twice ?

Comment: @CDP1802 good point, well made

Comment: @CDP1802 add that as an answer and I will accept it.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing one of these lines

```vb
    .setRequestHeader "Client_Id", client_id
    .setRequestHeader "Client_Id", client_id
```

Comment: Thanks!!  Can't see for looking sometimes